# How to reduce Typescript dist size?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, node-modules

I'm building a NodeJS app wrapped into a Docker container. I want to make this image as light as possible. I've already applied the usual techniques like installing only prod deps, using `node-prune` etc. But my `node_modules` folder is still huge and filled mostly with typescript, tslib, type definitions etc.

Since I need to run `tsc` inside the container, I assume I can somehow clean up the node_modules after it.

```
RUN tsc
```

I could just `RUN rm node_modules/something` commands, but this seems like a dangerous approach. Is there a better way to lighten docker container with a tsc app?

Comment: You can use a bundler like webpack or rollup to bundle everything (including dependencies) into a single javascript file and you will no longer need to include your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Why can't you compile outside the container and just put the .js and .d.ts files in the container, like a normally distributed application? Of course you might need node_modules for runtime dependencies but why tsc?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-prune? Or use a multi-stage build, so you can copy only the build outputs into the final image (as I do here: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit-ts/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Comment: You can have a look at [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc). It bundles your code with all its dependencies in a single file that you can then execute. It supports typescript out of the box.